# Problem apache server (re-)Installation

Tags: 12.04, server, apache2, uninstall

I am newbie in Ubuntu and I removed all apache file following command

```
sudo chown user /etc/init.d/apache2
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/apache2
sudo rm /etc/init.d/apache2
```

I know its wrong way to removing apache, now I want to install apache again

**Edit**
try to reinstal apache

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2
```

working fine,but when I type command

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

response as,

```
apache2: unrecognized service
```

Comment: Probably the same question, with upvoted answers: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12597/missing-init-d-apache2-file .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally i got the solution

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo apt-get remove --purge $APACHE_PKGS
sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2
```

Comment: glad you have found that and thanks for adding . it will be useful for future reference.

Comment: Did not solve the problem.

Comment: @reggie  it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal and type this

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2
```

Comment: command is working fine,but "sudo service apache2 start" giving me error "apache2: unrecognized service"

Comment: @AmitDubey - Confirm whether your `apache2` service is installed by checking with `dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep "apache2"`. This will give you an output if the packages in installed.

Comment: @AzkerM thanks for reply,command out put is "apache2=>install"
"apache2-bin=>install",
"apache2-data=>install"

Comment: seems like you've the packages in place. Try `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload` or `sudo apache2ctl graceful` to have a look through again.

Comment: Good to hear! :)